# EditText value inside GridView Changing When Scrolling up/down Fast

Tags: android, gridview

I have a custom GridView. This is my app's screesnhot :

[image]

And now when I'm scrolling down quickly the value inside editText (2) in AYAMBROILER UTUH changes into another cell. This is the screenshot :

[image]

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

This is my adapter code :

```
public class CustomGridView2 extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;
    private int count = 0;
    int arrayCount[];
    SharedPreferences prefs ;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    public CustomGridView2(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.afterlogin_product_gridview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama_produk);
            holder.teaserView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.harga);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_produk);
            holder.cmdMinus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_min);
            holder.cmdPlus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
            holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
            holder.layout1 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
        String satuan = newsItem.getSatuan().toString();
        String harga = newsItem.getReporterName().toString();
        harga = "Rp. " + harga + " / " + satuan;
        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline().toUpperCase());
        holder.teaserView.setText(harga);

        String a = newsItem.getUrl();
        holder.cmdPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count = Integer.parseInt( holder.qty.getText().toString());
                count++;
                holder.qty.setText(""+count);
            }
        });

        holder.cmdMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count = Integer.parseInt( holder.qty.getText().toString());

                if(count == 0) {
                    holder.qty.setText("0");
                }
                else {
                    count--;
                    holder.qty.setText("" + count);
                }
            }
        });

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            //new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
            Picasso
                    .with(context)
                    .load(a)
                    .fit()
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }



        holder.qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!holder.qty.getText().toString().matches("0"))
                {
                    holder.layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_radius_gridview);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_radius);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView teaserView;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView satuan,qty;
        Button cmdPlus,cmdMinus;
        LinearLayout layout1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ViewHolder pattern The views are reusing as it is...So, While clicking plus or minus add quantity to the ListItem object and show it from the object..

```
holder.teaserView.setText(harga);
holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newsItem.getQuantity()));

String a = newsItem.getUrl();
holder.cmdPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    count = newsItem.getQuantity();
    count++;
    newsItem.setQuantity(count);
    holder.qty.setText(""+count);
}
});

holder.cmdMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
count = newsItem.getQuantity();
if(count == 0) {
  holder.qty.setText("0");
}
else {
count--;
newsItem.setQuantity(count);
holder.qty.setText("" + count);
}
}
});
```

Comment: Great ! You help me a lot !

Comment: Could you help me at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110188/first-time-sharedpreferences-use-with-gridview?noredirect=1#comment61799691_37110188 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that the views are reused in all scrollable views - recylcerview listview and gridview. SO when the views are reused their value shows up in places it should not. Have a look at the below link to solve your issue.

[EditText loses content on scroll in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772714/edittext-loses-content-on-scroll-in-listview)

If you have any doubt let me know.

Comment: I still don't get it. Where is 'scoresToUpdate' coming from ? Is it same as 'newsItem' in my code ?